# Issue providing Facebook ID and Scheme In phoneGap

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, cordova

Hi I am working in phoneGap. I want to integrate facebook in my app using phonegap. I am following the tutorial :

```
https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect/
```

In this tutorial(Read Me) it says that include Facebook ID and Scheme ID in the [projectName]info.plist. BUt the given data is :

```
   <key>FacebookAppID</key>
   <string>[**APP_ID**]</string>
   <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
   <array>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fb[**APP_ID**]</string>
    </array>
</dict>
   </array>
```

Here I am a bit confused that where I have to put my FaceBook ID and where to put Scheme ID ?? 
Kindly help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found a blog post - 
[Facebook plugin integration for PhoneGap 2.1 for iOS and Android](http://oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Facebook-plugin-integration-for-PhoneGap-2.1-for-iOS-and-Android) which says to do like

```
<strong><strong>
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>[SCHEME_ID]</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb[APP_ID]</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
</strong></strong>
```

from the same blogpost :

> SCHEME_ID and APP_ID SCHEME_ID is a unparalleled identifier in reverse
> domain order (i.e com.oodles.cordova.myscheme), APP_ID is the app id
> which you get after registering your app with facebook.

Comment: couldn't parse contents of '/Users/Burhan/Desktop/ExampleFaceBook/ExampleFaceBook/ExampleFaceBook-Info.plist': The data couldn’t be read because it has been corrupted.

Comment: @BurhanMughal that can be issue with your ExampleFaceBook-Info.plis‌​t look into this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7098306/1276002

Comment: I am giving scheme ID as .. com.facebook.phonegap.myscheme .. is here something got wrong ?

Comment: because when i remove this it gives another error and not this one .. it gives linker error

Comment: You may be missing the bundle ID entry in your App Dashboard settings. So go to http://developers.facebook.com/apps and enter the bundle iD that matches your Xcode project.