# UTF-8 encoding validator online

Tags: validation, utf-8

Hello I would like to test an URL encoding in UTF-8 Is there some online tools to do that?
The closest I have found is in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115210/utf-8-validation) which finally suggest to test on the client side using GNU.

note: I need to do that by code. Like sending the chars to enconde on a GET petition.

Comment: It depends entirely on which programming language you are using.  Most modern languages will have methods to convert a binary string into Unicode and (usually) a mode to reject invalid input.  For example, in Python, `unicode = your_input_string.decode('utf-8')` -- wrap that in a `try`/`except UnicodeEncodeError` to catch any encoding errors.