# iOS utf-8 encoding issue

Tags: ios, encoding, utf-8

i try get html page with UTF-8 charset

```
NSString *html=[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:  @"http://forums.drom.ru/general/t1151288178.html"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error]);
```

but `NSLog(@"%@",html)` return null
Why is this happening?

Comment: I wonder if your russian site is actually encoded UTF8... Have you tried other encoding options?

Comment: I think the request maybe timedout, you may use NSURLRequest or other HTTP frameworks to fetch contents.

Comment: Using of other encoding options didn't help me. Rob is right, page contain incorrect UTF8 characters in clever_cut_pattern variable. 
I use [method](https://gist.github.com/cherpake/4709652) for removing this characters from NSData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that while the file's meta tag purports to be UTF8, it's not (at least not entirely). You can confirm this by:

- Download the html (as `NSData`, which succeeds):

  ```
  NSError *error = nil;
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://forums.drom.ru/general/t1151288178.html"];
  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:&error];
  NSString *docsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
  NSString *filename = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.html"];
  [data writeToFile:filename atomically:YES];
  ```
- Run `iconv` from the Terminal command line, it will report an error (including line number and character number):

  ```
  iconv -f UTF-8 test.html > /dev/null
  ```

  Thanks to [Torsten Marek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/115262/1271826) for sharing that with us.

When I look at that portion of the HTML, there are definitely not UTF8 characters there, buried in the setting of the `clever_cut_pattern` JavaScript variable.

If we thought you just got the encoding wrong, the typical counsel in these cases would generally be to use the rendition of `stringWithContentOfURL` with the `usedEncoding` parameter (i.e. rather than guessing what the encoding is, let `NSString` determine this for you):

```
NSStringEncoding encoding;
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error];
```

Unfortunately, in this case, even that fails (presumably because the file purports to be UTF8, but isn't).

The question then becomes "ok, so what do I do now". It depends upon why you were trying to download that HTML in your app, anyway. If you really need to convert this to UTF8 (i.e. strip out the non-UTF8 characters), you could theoretically get the GNU `iconv(3)` [function](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libiconv/documentation/libiconv-1.13/iconv.3.html), which is part of the `libiconv` [library](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libiconv/). That could identify non-conforming characters that you could presumably remove. It's a question of how much work you're willing to go through to handle this non-conforming web page.