# Treatment of spaces in sort command. Difference between LC_COLLATE=c and LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"

Tags: linux, shell, sorting, unix

I tried to look this up in the man pages of the `sort` command, but could not find anything.
So consider the following text file `t.txt`:

```
 11
1 0
```

(Binary representation of `t.txt`

```
$ xxd -p t.txt
2031310a3120300a
```

)

using `LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"` with `sort` on this file gives:

```
$  LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8" sort t.txt
1 0
 11
```

If we examine the second character position (or column) in the file, we observe that the first
row has a space, and the second row has a `1`.
Since space has hexadecimal value of `0x20` which is less than the hexadecimal value of `1` (which is `0x31`) 
I would assume that sort would give:

```
 11
1 0
```

It turns out that the expected sorting order can be obtained using `LC_COLLATE=c`

```
$ LC_COLLATE=c sort t.txt
 11
1 0
```

What is the reason for the difference between `LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"` and `LC_COLLATE=c` for this case?

See also:

- [What does “LC_ALL=C” do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do)
- [Why does ls sorting ignore non-alphanumeric characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35469/why-does-ls-sorting-ignore-non-alphanumeric-characters)
- [How do locales work in Linux / POSIX and what transformations are applied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226851/how-do-locales-work-in-linux-posix-and-what-transformations-are-applied)
- [Internationalization: Collate (Sort) Order, Character Set, Accents, GLOB patterns](http://teaching.idallen.com/cst8177/13w/notes/000_character_sets.html)

**Edit:**

Some more information about this issue was found here:

- [In utf-8 collation, why 11- is less then 1-?](https://superuser.com/questions/227925/in-utf-8-collation-why-11-is-less-then-1)
- [UNICODE COLLATION ALGORITHM](http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/)
- [unix sort ignores whitespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923464/unix-sort-ignores-whitespaces)
- [Is gnu coreutils sort broken?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4422/is-gnu-coreutils-sort-broken)
- [Why does 'sort' ignore special characters, like the asterisk?](https://superuser.com/questions/226449/why-does-sort-ignore-special-characters-like-the-asterisk/)

Comment: It depends on your locale. Check for example `LC_ALL=C sort file`, that gives `A 11` first. See http://www.manpagez.com/info/coreutils/coreutils_196.php#SEC196

Comment: @fedorqui But why does it not work without `LC_ALL=C` ? (`echo $LANG` gives `en_US.UTF-8`)

Comment: @HåkonHægland The simple answer is "because the sorting rules are different in different locales". The full answer is probably quite a bit more complex...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

punctuation is ignored when ordering in the en_US locale

Note sort can explicitly skip whitespace with the -b option,
but note that's trick to use, so I'd advise using the sort --debug
option when using that.

Comment: Thanks! That is interesting. I also found some more information here: [In utf-8 collation, why 11- is less then 1-?](http://superuser.com/questions/227925/in-utf-8-collation-why-11-is-less-then-1) and [UNICODE COLLATION ALGORITHM](http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/).