# How can Perl and Unix sort, order Unicode strings in the same sequence?

Tags: perl, sorting, unix, unicode, locale

I am trying to get Perl and the GNU/Linux *sort*(1) program agree on how to sort Unicode strings. I'm running *sort* with `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`. In the Perl program I have tried the following methods:

- [`use Unicode::Collate`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Unicode::Collate) with `$Collator = Unicode::Collate->new();`
- [`use Unicode::Collate::Locale`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Unicode::Collate::Locale) with `$Collator = Unicode::Collate->new(locale => $ENV{'LANG'});`
- [`use locale`](http://perldoc.perl.org/locale.html)

Each one of them failed with the following errors (from the Perl side):

- Input is not sorted: [----,] came after [($1]
- Input is not sorted: [...] came after [&]
- Input is not sorted: [($1] came after [1]

The only method that worked for me involved setting `LC_ALL=C` for *sort*, and using 8-bit characters in Perl.  However, in this way Unicode strings are not properly ordered.

Comment: Are you calling `sort` properly?  Unicode::Collate doesn't change the default behavior of `sort`; you have to use a custom comparison function.

Comment: I'm actually implementing merge-sort in Perl, so I'm not calling Perl's sort function.  But, yes, I'm using code such as `print STDERR "Input is not sorted: [$key] came after [$prev]\n" if (defined($prev) && $Collator->cmp($key, $prev) < 0);`

Comment: The actual Perl code (for 8-bit characters) is at https://github.com/dspinellis/sgsh/blob/master/sgsh-merge-sum.pl.  It is designed to merge the output of multiple `sort | uniq -c` invocations.

Comment: and you're using `export LANG=...; export LC_LOCALE=...`, right? Good luck.

Comment: Note that `sort` uses `LC_COLLATE`, not `LANG`.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226851/how-do-locales-work-in-linux-posix-and-what-transformations-are-applied

Comment: @shellter: yes, I'm exporting the variables.

Comment: @ikegami: sort(1) seems to take into account LANG as well.  

Running "(echo B ; echo a) | LANG=C sort" gives "B a", whereas running "(echo B ; echo a) | LANG=en_US.UTF-8 sort" gives "a
B".

I agree that LC_COLLATE is more specific.

Comment: On linux, LANG has no effect as documented. Both give the same output (`B a` with `LC_COLLATE=C`, `a B` with `LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8`).

Comment: That is to be expected.  The precedence is LC_COLLATE, if not defined LC_ALL, if not defined LANG.  See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xbd/envvar.html

Comment: Side note: Do you know about `sort -m`? I know Unicode sorting should be the same everywhere but different tools may yield different results due to bugs or using different revisions of Unicode (not sure if the sort order may ever change but I think so).

Comment: Thank you, yes, I know about sort -m, but it doesn't fit my purpose. I want to sum the output of multiple sort | uniq -c runs, and sort -m can't do that.

Comment: Which version of Perl are you using?

Comment: This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread

Comment: While the question says "Perl and the GNU/Linux sort" , the previous comment says "MSWin32". There may be a mismatch if the output is generated on two systems ( linux and windows ) and then compared. Try running both perl and sort on linux only.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  My question concerns a system that will be distributed as open source; I don't want to dictate where / how people will use it.  Rather I was hoping that standards would provide a portable solution.

Comment: Why not use use `sort` through IPC::Run3?

Comment: Because the Perl program's functionality (an extension to sort -m) is not covered by the functionality of sort.  The examples in my question are just minimal use cases to demonstrate the problem.  I was hoping that standards would offer a way for the two tools to behave in the same way.

Answer (score 4):

Using Unicode::Sort or Unicode::Sort::Locale makes no sense. You're not trying to sort based on Unicode definitions, you're trying to sort based on your locale. That's what `use locale;` is for.

I don't know why you didn't get the desired order out of `cmp` under `use locale;`.

You could process the decompressed files.

```
for q in file1.uniqc file2.uniqc ; do
   perl -ne's/^\s*(\d+) //; for $c (1..$1) { print }' "$q"
done | sort | uniq -c
```

It'll require more temporary storage, of course, but you'll get exactly the order you want.

---

I found a case `use locale;` didn't cause Perl's `sort`/`cmp` to give the same result as the `sort` utility. Weird.

```
$ export LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8

$ perl -Mlocale -e'print for sort { $a cmp $b } <>' data
(
($1
1

$ perl -MPOSIX=strcoll -e'print for sort { strcoll($a, $b) } <>' data
(
($1
1

$ sort data
(
1
($1
```

Truth be told, it's the `sort` utility that's weird.

---

In the comments, @ninjalj points out that the weirdness is probably due to characters with undefined weights. When comparing such characters, the ordering is undefined, so different engines could produce different results. Your best bet to recreate the exact order would be to use the `sort` utility through [IPC::Run3](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::Run3), but it sounds like that's not guaranteed to always result in the same order.

Comment: I'm benchmarking performance on a 20GB data set, so I can't afford a suboptimal solution.  The case you describe is exactly the type of problem I'm facing. Note that I don't care a lot about the particular locale that will be used, as long as it works reasonably with Unicode strings (e.g. DUCET), and it works the same with sort(1) and Perl.

Comment: Re "I'm benchmarking performance on a 20GB data set", So what was the resul?

Comment: RE "it works the same with sort(1) and Perl", Is that really true? Do you actually need to use the `sort` utility?

Comment: Doesn't Perl use the UCA for sorting, while glibc uses ISO 14651?

Comment: @ninjalj, I thought locale-based sorting was defined by system files? (I heard about broken locale on machines many times.)

Comment: I think this is due to characters without weight in the locale tables. ISO 14651 §6.2.2 says: _The ordering of characters with undefined weights with respect to other characters with undefined weights is not specified in this International Standard_, while the UCA §7.1.3 gives them implicit weights.

Comment: Re: "So what's the [benchmark] result?" On a single node 8-core machine I find sort(1) + Perl to be orders of magnitude faster than Hadoop.  But Perl+sort work on 8-bit characters, whereas Hadoop works on Unicode.  So I want to level the playing field.

Comment: Regarding the difference between ISO 14651 and UCA I read that "The Common Tailorable Template (CTT) datafile of [the ISO 14651] Standard is aligned with the Default Unicode Collation Entity Table (DUCET) datafile of the Unicode Collation Algorithm (UCA) specified in Unicode Technical Standard #10." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_14651  Note that my input consists only of ASCII characters.

Comment: No, the proposed solution. You implied it was suboptimal, so you must have tested it, right?

Comment: I reasoned based on algorithmic complexity: O(N) of the original vs O(N log N) of the proposed solution, but you're right I should have tested it.  Back soon with the benchmark results.

Comment: I finished the benchmark.  With Perl "uncompressing" the files and then running again "sort | uniq -c" execution time rose from 38:49 to 41:40.

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer directly, but I had problems getting a simple script to sort Serbian Latin text correctly, I found https://www.perl.com/pub/2012/06/perlunicook-demo-of-unicode-collation-and-printing.html/, copied his setup (my actual processing is much simpler than his), and finally got the correct alphabetic sorting for that language and locale.  There's about as much as anyone would need to know about Unicode linguistic sorting in the whole set of guides at https://www.perl.com/pub/2012/04/perlunicook-standard-preamble.html/.

I assume you want to sort Greek.  Here's a very simple version of what I copied and adapted from the guide, which sorts correctly.

```
# min required setup for trial sort
use utf8;
use v5.14; # for locale sorting and unicode_strings
use Unicode::Normalize;
use Unicode::Collate::Locale;
my @words = qw{
        Η
        Ιθάκη
        σ'
        έδωσε
        το
        ωραίο
        ταξίδι.
        Χωρίς
        αυτήν
        δεν
        θάβγαινες
        στον
        δρόμο.
};
print "Unsorted: @words\n";
my $coll = Unicode::Collate::Locale->new( locale => "el_GR" );
my @sorted_words = $coll->sort(@words);
print "Sorted: @sorted_words\n";
```