# How does the linux utility "sort" work? (why does it not work the way I think it should?)

Tags: linux, sorting

I have 2 text files:

```
$ cat /tmp/test1
"AAP" bar
"AEM" bar
"AA" bar
"AEO" bar
"A" bar

$ cat /tmp/test2
"AEM" foo
"AAP" foo
"A" foo
"AEO" foo
"AA" foo
```

I want to sort them

```
$ sort /tmp/test1
"AA" bar
"AAP" bar
"A" bar              <-- "A" is in position 3
"AEM" bar
"AEO" bar

$ sort /tmp/test2
"AA" foo
"AAP" foo
"AEM" foo
"AEO" foo
"A" foo              <-- "A" is in position 5
```

Why does `"A"` end up in **position 3 in `/tmp/test1`** and in **position 5 in `/tmp/test2`**?

My expectation is that **each character per column** will be compared.

As such, when comparing column 3, `'A'`, `'E'` and `'"'` will be compared against each other, and this would be the ultimate determinant in the final sort order of this test data.

Clearly my expectation is wrong, so how does `sort` work, if not in the way I expected?

Is there command line option to `sort` or some other utility I can use to get the sort order I desire?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25835561/how-can-perl-and-unix-sort-order-unicode-strings-in-the-same-sequence

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default `sort` will work on the whole line and do so in a locale specific manner, with some locales ignoring some characters (the quote and space in your case). To figure out what's going on, try the --debug option. I.E. compare and contrast:

```
sort --debug /tmp/test[12]
LC_ALL=C sort --debug /tmp/test[12]
sort --debug -k1,1 /tmp/test[12]
LC_ALL=C sort --debug -k1,1 /tmp/test[12]
```

BTW, you can add a -s option to avoid the last resort sort to simplify the --debug output.