# Remove invalid non-ASCII characters in Bash

Tags: bash, ascii, utf, non-ascii-characters

In Bash (on Ubuntu), is there a command which removes invalid multibyte (non-ASCII) characters?

I've tried `perl -pe 's/[^[:print:]]//g'` but it also removes all valid non-ASCII characters.

I can use `sed`, `awk` or similar utilities if needed.

Comment: What is a multibyte character?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I meant non-ASCII, I'll edit the post

Comment: This may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115210/utf-8-validation

Comment: What do you consider invalid? For example, is an unassigned codepoint valid or invalid?

Comment: So how's `iconv` working for you?

Comment: @professorfish: In that case, you'll need to use a unicode-aware regex engine which understands unicode general category codes. You'll want to remove general categories Cn (unassigned), Cs (surrogate), and probably Co (private use). `Cn` is relative to a particular Unicode version; in future versions Cn codepoints may be assigned (aside from the 66 non-characters).

Comment: @ooga I tried `iconv -c`, it removes most of the invalid characters but some still display as � (question mark) or ߻ (box with hex numbers in it). Is it just because they aren't in my font?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that Perl does not realize that your input is UTF-8; it assumes it's operating on a stream of bytes. You can use the `-CI` flag to tell it to interpret the input as UTF-8. And, since you will then have multibyte characters in your *output*, you will also need to tell Perl to use UTF-8 in writing to standard output, which you can do by using the `-CO` flag. So:

```
perl -CIO -pe 's/[^[:print:]]//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simpler alternative to Perl, try `iconv` as follows:

```
iconv -c <<<$'Mot\x{fc}rhead'  # -> 'Motrhead'
```

- Both the input and output encodings default to UTF-8, but can be specified explicitly: the input encoding with `-f` (e.g., `-f UTF8`); the output encoding with `-t` (e.g., `-t UTF8`) - run `iconv -l` to see all supported encodings.
- `-c` simply discards input chars. that aren't valid in the input encoding; in the example, `\x{fc}` is the single-byte LATIN1 (ISO8859-1) representation of `ö`, which is invalid in UTF8 (where it's represented as `\x{c3}\x{b6}`).

Note (after discovering a comment by the OP): If your output still contains garbled characters:

> "� (question mark) or ߻ (box with hex numbers in it)"

the implication is indeed that the cleaned-up string contains - valid - UTF-8 characters that the font being used doesn't support.