# heroku JSON::GeneratorError: source sequence is illegal/malformed utf-8 when trying to deploy rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, utf-8, assets, precompile

Since I have added external css and js files to my rails app, I am encountering problems deploying my app to Heroku. I get the following error when the assets are precompiled :

```
JSON::GeneratorError: source sequence is illegal/malformed utf-8
```

As suggested in [rake aborted! JSON::GeneratorError: source sequence is illegal/malformed utf-8 after rake assets:precompile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31372478/rake-aborted-jsongeneratorerror-source-sequence-is-illegal-malformed-utf-8-a), I installed isutf8 and ran the following command at my app folder level :

```
isutf8 *
```

[image]

It doesnt return any output which makes me think that the files in my app folder are valid utf8.
Am I using the isutf8 tool correctly ? If yes, it should output invalid utf8 files as this is why heroku is crashing right ?

Comment: I suppose that colouring procedure breaks the utf8 sequence, but what dd you show on the picture?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ what does dd stand for ?

Comment: i meant what did you shewn the pricture from?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ it's just how my terminal window looks like when I try to run isutf8 on the folder quick_bed_front