# RStudio wont show Unicode characters when knit to PDF

Tags: r, unicode

Below is my code

> cat("\U30C1", "\U30A7", "\U30C3" , "\U30AF" , "\U30A4" , "\U30F3" , "\U30ED" 
>       , "\U30D3" , "\U30FC")

When it is run in R studio is looks like this (which is how it is supposed to)

> チ ェ ッ ク イ ン ロ ビ ー

However when I knit it to PDF it outputs like this

> U+30C1 U+30A7 U+30C3 U+30AF U+30A4 U+30F3 U+30EDU+30D3 U+30FC

Does anyone know how to fix this so the Japanese symbols can be on the PDF?

Comment: Some poking around suggested that switching to the xelatex engine might be necessary and perhaps using a different base font (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39207334/1457051)